# How to group a column and further group another column based on spedified value and counting them (Pandas Python)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The Table for required data is provided below

I want to group the columns by User Name first and count the occurences of a single disposition code for that username

```
User Name Disposition Code
person1    Solved
person2    Solved
person1    Solved
person2    Not Solved
person3    Solved
```

Result required:

```
User Name Total Solved Total Not Solved
person1     2              0
person2     1              1
peson3      1              0
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Also you can use `groupby`with `value_counts` + `unstack`:

```
new_df=df.groupby('User_Name')['Disposition_Code'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).unstack(fill_value=0)
print(new_df)

           Not_Solved  Solved
User_Name                    
person1             0       2
person2             1       1
person3             0       1
```

---

**To get a join_df**:

**Option 1**

```
join_df=df.copy()
join_df['count']=new_df.lookup(df['User_Name'],df['Disposition_Code'])
print(join_df)

  User_Name Disposition_Code  count
0   person1           Solved      2
1   person2           Solved      1
2   person1           Solved      2
3   person2       Not_Solved      1
4   person3           Solved      1
```

**Option 2**

```
join_df=df.copy()
join_df['count']=df.groupby(['User_Name','Disposition_Code'])['User_Name'].transform('size')
```

Comment: And how do i join the both old_df and new_df in same table with Key="User Name"? as i need to write to CSV file

Comment: Then you would need to add an additional column. Look at the code that I added in my answer. Please consider voting my answer. Thank you!.

Comment: if you consider join_df incorrect in my answer you could add what would be the join_df dataframe that you want to get in your question

Comment: I am getting error mentioned below while trying to execute the join KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'

Comment: then use: `join_df=df.copy()
join_df['count']=df.groupby(['User_Name','Disposition_Code'])['User_Name'].transform('size')`

Comment: test.groupby("User Name").agg({"Total Offered Calls": ['sum']
                                                 , "Calls Received": ['mean']
                                                 , "Total Served In Target": ['sum']
                                                 , "Total Served In Target %": ['mean']
                                                 , "DispositionCode": ['count']
                                                 , "Total Served After Target": ['sum']})  Dispostion code is a string. how do i count it. as it is giving error. not 1 dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['UserName'], columns=df['DispositionCode'])

Disposition Code  Not Solved  Solved
UserName                          
person1                  0       2
person2                  1       1
person3                  0       1
```